# Download File in Specified folder [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, download

I've been creating a small project with the aim of downloading youtube videos on my server. in theory it already works, but I want that, when I press download, it downloads the file in a specific folder inside the server.

this is my code for the function.

Used library: ytdl-core

```
app.get("/download", async(req, res) => {
    const info = await req.query.url;
    const v_id = info.split('v=')[1];
    res.header("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="${v_id}.mp3`);
    ytdl(info, {format: 'mp3'}).pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Instead of piping it to the response sent to the server, pipe it [into a file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatewritestreamoptions). (EDIT: Not sure why the page jumps around afterwards, but I was trying to link to the docs of `fs.createWriteStream`.)

Comment: @CherryDT how could i do this? I'm new.

Comment: I linked the docs to `fs.createWriteStream` that describe the function which creates a write stream for you to pipe ytdl's output into, so you'd have `.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(.....))` instead of `.pipe(res)`. (Then don't forget to returns something else in your response though, like a string `OK` or a redirection, otherwise the request would just appear to hang.)